# Calculating joint probability density

Tags: probability, analysis

Say I have $n$ independent random variable $X_1,...,X_n: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on a probability space $\Omega$ with the same density $p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$. Could someone explain to me in the most measure-theoretic terms (i.e. assuming I know plenty of measure theory but not much probability theory terminology) how you can explicitly write down the *density* of the joint probability distribution $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ of $X_1$ and $t= \sum_{j=1}^nX_j$ using only $p$?  For instance I have an example where $p(x) = xe^{-x}$, and I'm supposed to get $$\frac{1}{\Gamma ( 2n-2)}x_1(t-x_1)^{2n-3}e^{-t}$$ for the density of the joint distribution.

Comment: The density can be viewed as mappping $[0,\infty)^2$ into $[0,\infty).$ Thus you could say $\text{“} \ldots \text{for } x_1\ge0,\, t\ge 0.\text{''} \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry I don't understand. The density isn't defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$?  Or its determined by its values on nonnegative $x_1, t$?

Comment: It can be taken to be defined on all of $\mathbb R^2$ but equal to $0$ except in the first quadrant.

Comment: You have $p(x) = xe^{-x}$ for $x\ge0.$ Note that
$$(\,\underbrace{p* \cdots \cdots *p}_{(n-1)\text{-fold} \\ \text{convolution}}\,)(x) = \frac 1 {\Gamma(2(n-1))} x^{2(n-1)-1} e^{-x} \quad \text{for } x\ge 0,$$
where the convolution $f*g$ of $f$ and $g$ is
$$
(f*g)(w) = \int_0^w f(x)g(w-x) \, dx.
$$
If we have two _independent_ random variables $U,V$ for which $\Pr(U\ge0) = \Pr(V\ge 0) =1,$ with respective probability density functions $f,g,$ then their joint density is $(u,v)\mapsto f(u) g(v),$ and the probability density function of the sum $X+Y$ is then$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$the convolution $f*g.$ You should be able to prove by induction that the $(n-1)$-fold convolution is as asserted above. $\qquad$

Comment: But then you must also deal with the non-independence of $X_1$ and the sum. More later, maybe$\,\ldots\,\qquad$

Comment: Ok thanks. Yes, so the correlation between $X_1$ and the sum is the missing piece.

Comment: @MichaelHardy btw I'm self-studying stats partially as a result of being inspired by your excellent answer to "statistics for mathematicians" on MO :)

Comment: So one of my answers got noticed. :-) $\qquad$

Comment: One fact that may be worth knowing here is that the functions $$ f_\alpha (x) = \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha)} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x} \quad \text{for } x>0$$ with $\alpha> 0$ satisfy $$f_\alpha * f_\beta = f_{\alpha+\beta}$$ (where the asterisk represents convolution as above). $\qquad$

Comment: . . . . . and therefore if $X,Y$ are independent random variables with probability densities $f_\alpha, f_\beta$ then $X+Y$ has probability density $f_{\alpha+\beta}. \qquad$

Comment: . . . and you're looking at the case $\alpha=2. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

What if you just push the measure from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ via $$L: (x_1,...,x_{n-1}, x_n)\mapsto (x_1,...,x_{n-1},\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)$$ and then project down $ \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ via

$$\pi :(x_1,...,x_{n-1}, t)\mapsto (x_1,t).$$

Then the density function is easy to track: Since $L$ has an inverse, the density $p$ goes to  $p\circ L^{-1}$ and then since $\pi$ is just a projection, the density can be pushed down just by integrating over the fibers of points.

You will need the following identity,

$$\frac{C^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} = \int_{A_k(C)}\big(C-\sum_{i=1}^k x_i\big)\cdot x_1x_2...x_k~~ dx_1dx_2...dx_k,$$

where $$A_k(C):= {\{(x_1,...,x_k)\in \mathbb{R}^k:~~~~\sum_{i=1}^k x_i\leq C,~~\text{and}~~ x_i\geq 0~~\text{for all} ~i~\}}.$$

This can be proved by induction:
$$\int_{A_k(C)}\big(C-\sum_{i=1}^k x_i\big)\cdot x_1x_2...x_k~~ dx_1dx_2...dx_k =$$  $$\int_0^C ~x_k \bigg( ~\int_{A_{k-1}(C-x_k)}\big((C-x_k)- \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} x_i\big)\cdot x_1x_2...x_{k-1}~~ dx_1dx_2...\bigg) ~dx_k=$$ $$\int_0^C ~x_k\frac{(C-x_k)^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!}dx_k.$$

Then just integrate by parts.